# Changed motherboard and can't get graphic card to work

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Basic question:  How can I get Ubuntu to recognize the Nvidia Graphics card?

Background information:

I replaced the motherboard on a PC I am building. The first motherboard did not recognize the internal GPU (iGPU).  So I changed to a motherboard that supports both a graphics card and the iGPU.  I am using the same o/s load from the first motherboard.  I just replaced the motherboard and rebooted, no other changes.  The graphics card worked as expected with the previous motherboard, but is not working as expected in Ubuntu with the new motherboard. I have also tested the hardware by loading Windows and both the iGPU and graphics card do work as expected in Windows on the new motherboard.  So I feel pretty confident it is not a motherboard issue.

The system configuration:

- Ubuntu 22.10
- MSI MGE Z690 Ace motherboard
- Intel i9-12900k CPU (which does have the iGPU)
- Nvidia GeForce RTX 3080 graphics card

I have the proper nvidia driver loaded.

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-525 is already the newest version (525.78.01-0ubuntu0.22.10.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

But nvidia does not see the driver

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

The graphics card and iGPU are both recognized by Ubuntu

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1)

$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel AlderLake-S GT1 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080 Lite Hash Rate] driver: N/A
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.3 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.3
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 43.1 driver: X: loaded: nouveau,vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 770 (ADL-S GT1) v: 4.6 Mesa
    22.2.5

$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080 Lite Hash Rate]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb1
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:640-63f memory:50000000-50ffffff memory:6000000000-63ffffffff memory:6400000000-6401ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:51000000-5107ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: AlderLake-S GT1
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb1
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: iomemory:640-63f iomemory:400-3ff irq:206 memory:6403000000-6403ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 3
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1680,1050
```

Of concern from the inxi command is that Device-2 has a driver of N/A, even though I have confirmed the nvidia driver is loaded.

there are a few errors at boot time that I don't understand:
[image: boot time errors]

I am not sure if the boot errors are relevant, but included just in case.

I tried using a test load of Ubuntu from USB, but that will not allow me to update the video driver to the nvidia driver in "try Ubuntu" mode.  I don't have a spare disk to load a fresh copy of the o/s too.  So I am trying to fix the current o/s load if possible.

The graphics driver is not what I would expect.  But it may be proper since the system has two different GPUs
[image: About info]

One other thing that is odd.  When I log in and change to x.org, the system hangs for a bit and then returns to the login prompt.

If the system is left running unused for a period of time, I have to issue a ctrl alt del in order to wake the screen.  That causes the system to reboot.  The system is still running properly when the screen is blank and won't wake, as I can access services it provides (Plex) from another computer when the screen is blank and the console is non-responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I did a full reload of Ubuntu and that resolved the issue.  It seemed like overkill, but I could not find anyother way to get both the iGPU and GPU recognized